# How to clear sqlite database on logout

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, offline-mode

I am using Xamarin Forms and the WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore NuGet to handle synchronization between my sqlite database and my azure database. Everything works fine, but when I want to logout my user I want to clean the database. This way on the next login, it will once again, regenerate the database and synchronize from zero. I have tried purging the tables but this only removes local data and when you log back in it will synchronize any new data only.

Currently my dispose does the following:

```
// Globally declared and initialized in my init() method
MobileServiceSQLiteStore store { get; set; }
public MobileServiceClient MobileService { get; set; }

public async Task Dispose()
{
    try
    {
        initialized = false;

        // await this.userTable.PurgeAsync<AzureUser>("CleanUsers", this.userTable.CreateQuery(), CancellationToken.None);

        store.Dispose();
        MobileService.Dispose();

        store = null;
        MobileService = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Any idea of how I can clean my sqlite database on logout using this component? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried forcing a sync after purging the data? So doing `await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();` after `PurgeAsync()`?

Comment: @hvaughan3 Once the user logs back in it syncronizes once again but the  purged data isn't syncronized instead only new records are synced.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to purge all items, use:

```
this.userTable.PurgeAsync(null, null, true, CancellationToken.None);
```

[See the code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/fd559611a7af8bfb5aa9d51ba30ad3b48b80a832/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Extensions/MobileServiceSyncTableExtensions.cs#L286).

Comment: Here's a sample: https://github.com/lindydonna/ContosoMoments/blob/dev/src/Mobile/ContosoMoments/App.cs#L132

Comment: Sorry, I just got around to seeing this since I had a change in priorities of what needed to be done. The purgeAsync method cleans the local databases, but when the user logs in once again it syncronizes only new rows added in azure and not the rows that where purged previously... Any idea why this could be happening?